# Removing line elements in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm creating a line chart based on https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/examples/line/line.html .

```
var data = [
  {x: 0, y: 3},
  {x: 1, y: 4},
  {x: 2, y: 5}
];

var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.x); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.y); });
line.interpolate('monotone');

var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line);
```

How do I remove the last element from the path (i.e. delete a line segment)?  Similar examples for removing elements involve changing the data array, and re-initializing via exit.  In the case of 'circles' this looks something like:

```
data.shift();
var circles = svg.selectAll(".dot").data(data);
circles.exit().remove();
```

However this approach doesn't work with path.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `data.shift()` with `data = data.splice(0, data.length - 1)`

[array.splice(index , howMany[, element1[, ...[, elementN]]])](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: You could also replace `data.shift()` with [`data.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the last data element before passing it to d3. Your code would be clearer if you moved the call to `.data()` further down to where the paths are appended, as it is used only there, i.e. something like

```
data.shift();
svg.selectAll("path").data(data).enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", line);
```